# Reduce number of ndf-files in SQL-server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with 1 primary file in the PRIMARY filegroup and 1 default filegroup called DATA1 with 8 ndf-files, and one log file.

This can be seen below:

```
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------+
|   Logical name    | File Type |   Filegroup    | Type |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------+
| Database1_Primary | Rows Data | PRIMARY        | MDF  |
| Database1_Data1   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data2   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data3   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data4   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data5   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data6   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data7   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data8   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Log     | Log       | Not applicable | LDF  |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------+
```

This database is getting moved to another server, where I would like to have only 4 ndf-files.

Furthermore I would like to spread the data evenly between the 4 ndf-files?

This is the result i'm going for:

```
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------+
|   Logical name    | File Type |   Filegroup    | Type |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------+
| Database1_Primary | Rows Data | PRIMARY        | MDF  |
| Database1_Data1   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data2   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data3   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Data4   | Rows Data | DATA1          | NDF  |
| Database1_Log     | Log       | Not applicable | LDF  |
+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------+
```

So I have taken a backup of the database, and I'm looking for a T-SQL RESTORE-script, that can reduce the number of ndf-files to 4?

Thanks!

Comment: No such creature. `RESTORE` cannot alter the number of files in a file group on the fly. (You can choose not to restore some files in a piecemeal restore operation, but that's something different.) You'll need to restore all existing files, then migrate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DBCC SHRINKFILE` with `EMPTYFILE`..Below is what documemtation states

> Migrates all data from the specified file to other files in the same filegroup. In other words, EmptyFile will migrate the data from the specified file to other files in the same filegroup. Emptyfile assures you that no new data will be added to the file.The file can be removed by using the ALTER DATABASE statement.

Below is the syntax

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(LogicalNameOfFileToRemove, EMPTYFILE)
```

After that one  can remove those files using `Alter statement`

```
Alter database dbname
remove filegroupname
```

Finally ,after restoring this DB in new server , you can add required `ndf` files again

> Furthermore I would like to spread the data evenly between the 4 ndf-files

SQL does that for you..From this link [File and Filegroup Fill Strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups)

> Filegroups use a proportional fill strategy across all the files within each filegroup. As data is written to the filegroup, the SQL Server Database Engine writes an amount proportional to the free space in the file to each file within the filegroup, instead of writing all the data to the first file until full. It then writes to the next file. For example, if file f1 has 100 MB free and file f2 has 200 MB free, one extent is allocated from file f1, two extents from file f2, and so on. In this way, both files become full at about the same time, and simple striping is achieved